# Datetime format in PHP with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb, datetime, format

I'm getting problems while filtering data from a MongoDB where documents have a "iso_date" field like

```
ISODate("2010-08-01T00:00:00Z")
```

in the following .php file,

```
<?php

$date_a = $_GET['date_a'];
$date_b = $_GET['date_b'];

$m = new MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:xxxxx');
$db = $m->db;
$collection = $db->collection;

$res  = $collection->find(array(
            'iso_date' => array('$gte' => $date_a, '$lte' => $date_b)
        ));
$m->close();

echo json_encode($res);

?>
```

where date_a and date_b are created in javascript. I've tried to add string "T00:00:00Z" to YYYY-MM-DD dates, but the result is always empty (and I'm sure it shouldn't be).
How can I solve this? I'd like not to convert everything to strings, and to keep a datetime format.

Comment: do you want iso_date as '2010-08-01 00:00:00' ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$collection = $db->collection;

$start =  $_GET['date_a'];
$end = $_GET['date_a'];

// find dates between 1/15/2010 and 1/30/2010
$collection->find(array("iso_date" => array('$gt' => $start, '$lte' => $end)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$date_a` and `$date_b` need to be instances of [`MongoDate`](http://php.net/manual/pl/class.mongodate.php) (since you're using legacy driver chridam's answer may not work).